# subsetting a data.table based on a named list

Tags: r, list, data.table, subset

I'm trying to subset a given data.table

```
DT <- data.table(
  a = c(1:20),
  b = (3:4),
  c = (5:14),
  d = c(1:4)
)
```

within a function by a parameter which is a named list

```
param <- list(a = 1:10,
              b = 2:3,
              c = c(5, 7, 10))
```

I am maybe a bit stuck here but I certainly do not want implement something ugly like this. Especially since its not very dynamic.

```
DT[(if (!is.null(param$a))
  a %in% param$a
  else
    TRUE)
  &
    (if (!is.null(param$b))
      b %in% param$b
     else
       TRUE)
  &
    (if (!is.null(param$c))
      c %in%  param$c
     else
       TRUE)
  &
    (if (!is.null(param$d))
      d %in% param$d
     else
       TRUE)]
```

```
   a b c d
1: 1 3 5 1
2: 3 3 7 3
```

Any ideas how to achieve this in an elegant way in data.table or base R using  the names of the named list to subset the corresponding columns in the data.table with the associate values?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

I performed a microbenchmark with some of the answers:

```
func_4 <- function(myp, DT) {
  myp    = Filter(Negate(is.null), param)

  exs = Map(function(var, val)
    call("%in%", var, val),
    var = sapply(names(myp), as.name),
    val = myp)
  exi = Reduce(function(x, y)
    call("&", x, y), exs)
  ex = call("[", x = as.name("DT"), i = exi)
  # eval(as.call(c(as.list(ex))))
  eval(ex)
}

microbenchmark(
  (DT[do.call(pmin, Map(`%in%`, DT[, names(param), with = FALSE], param)) == 1L]),
  (DT[rowSums(mapply(`%in%`, DT[, names(param), with = FALSE], param)) == length(param)]),
  (DT[do.call(CJ, param), on = names(param), nomatch = NULL]),
  (DT[expand.grid(param), on = names(param), nomatch = NULL]),
  (DT[DT[, all(mapply(`%in%`, .SD, param)), by = 1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = names(param)]$V1]),
  (func_4(myp = param, DT = DT)),
  times = 200)

   min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
  446.656  488.5365  565.5597  511.403  533.7785  7167.847   200
  454.120  516.3000  566.8617  538.146  561.8965  1840.982   200
 2433.450 2538.6075 2732.4749 2606.986 2704.5285 10302.085   200
 2478.595 2588.7240 2939.8625 2642.311 2743.9375 10722.578   200
 2648.707 2761.2475 3040.4926 2814.177 2903.8845 10334.822   200
 3243.040 3384.6220 3764.5087 3484.423 3596.9140 14873.898   200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select columns in `DT` using `names` in `param`, apply `%in%` to every list element with columns and select only rows where all the values are `TRUE`.

```
DT[which(rowSums(mapply(`%in%`, DT[, names(param), with = FALSE],
      param)) == length(param)), ]

#   a b c d
#1: 1 3 5 1
#2: 3 3 7 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `CJ` (**C**ross **J**oin) function from `data.table` to make a filtering table from the list.

```r
lookup <- do.call(CJ, param)
head(lookup)
#    a b  c
# 1: 1 2  5
# 2: 1 2  7
# 3: 1 2 10
# 4: 1 3  5
# 5: 1 3  7
# 6: 1 3 10

DT[
    lookup,
    on = names(lookup),
    nomatch = NULL
]
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 1
# 2: 3 3 7 3
```

Note that `nomatch = 0` means any combo in `lookup` that doesn't exist in `DT` won't return a row.

Comment: Very nice. But could I not use `DT[expand.grid(param),
   on = names(param),
   nomatch = NULL]` instead?

Comment: @jaydee: Yes, `CJ` is pretty much the `data.table` version of `expand.grid`.  Two benefits of `CJ`: it doesn't convert strings to factors, and it handles list input consistently.  See the differences between `expand.grid(b = list(1, 2, 3))`, `expand.grid(a = 1, b = list(1, 2, 3))`, and how `CJ` handles those inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Map` we can do

```
DT[DT[, all(Map(`%in%`, .SD, param)), by = 1:nrow(DT)]$V1]
#   a b c d
#1: 1 3 5 1
#2: 3 3 7 3
```

For each row we check if all elements in `DT` are present in `param`.

---

Thanks to [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank), this can be improved to

```
DT[DT[, all(mapply(`%in%`, .SD, param)), by = 1:nrow(DT), .SDcols=names(param)]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but returns a lot of warnings:

...
`34: In all(Map(``%in%``, .SD, param)) : coercing argument of type 'list' to logical
35: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`
...

Answer (score 3):

You could build the expression with `call(fun, ...)` and `as.name`:

```
myp    = Filter(Negate(is.null), param)

exs = Map(function(var, val) call("%in%", var, val), var = sapply(names(myp), as.name), val = myp)
exi = Reduce(function(x,y) call("&", x, y), exs)
ex = call("[", x = as.name("DT"), i = exi)
# DT[i = a %in% 1:10 & b %in% 2:3 & c %in% c(5, 7, 10)]

eval(ex)
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 1
# 2: 3 3 7 3
```

By composing the call correctly, you can take advantage of efficient algorithms for "indices" in the data.table (see the package vignettes). You can also turn verbose on to get a note about the inefficiency of specifying `param$c` as numeric when `DT$c` is int:

```
> z <- as.call(c(as.list(ex), verbose=TRUE))
> eval(z)
Optimized subsetting with index 'c__b__a'
on= matches existing index, using index
Coercing double column i.'c' to integer to match type of x.'c'. Please avoid coercion for efficiency.
Starting bmerge ...done in 0.020sec 
   a b c d
1: 1 3 5 1
2: 3 3 7 3
```

That is, you should use `c(5L, 7L, 10L)`.

A join, as in Nathan's answer, also uses indices, but building and joining on the Cartesian table of `param` will be costly if `prod(lengths(param))` is large.

---

@markus approach may be slow due to by-row operation, so here is a variant:

```
DT[do.call(pmin, Map(`%in%`, DT[, names(param), with=FALSE], param)) == 1L]

#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 1
# 2: 3 3 7 3
```

The trick is that the elementwise version of `all` is `pmin(...) == 1L`. Likewise, `any` corresponds to `pmax(...) == 1L`. (This is why `pany`/`pall` are not included in this conversation on r-devel: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/There-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-how-about-psum-td4647841.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding another answer because the solutions presented by the OP are missing a critical detail: how each one scales with large datasets. I frequently work with datasets with well over 1m records, so for my own benefit I performed the microbenchmarking experiment the OP presents using datasets of different sizes for the `pmin` + `%in%` + `Map` solution and the `CJ` solution, a version of which I had implemented independently. Although the former is markedly faster for small datasets, the latter scales much better:

[image: Execution Time by Fields to Subset on]

It looks to me like the point where the relative speed switches is at ~200k records, regardless of the number of fields to subset on, so I packaged both functions into one for future use:

```
subsel <- function(x, sub, sel = NULL,
                   nomatch = getOption('datatable.nomatch')){
  #' function to subset data.table (x) using a named list (sub). sel
  #' can be used to return only the specified columns. algorithms
  #' copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728200/subsetting-a-data-table-based-on-a-named-list
  #' and cutoff decided on some ad hoc testing.
  if(is.null(sel)) sel <- names(x)
  if(x[, .N] < 200000L){
    return(
      x[
        do.call(
          pmin,
          Map(`%in%`, x[, .SD, .SDcols = names(sub)], sub)
        ) == 1L,
        .SD,
        .SDcols = sel,
        nomatch = nomatch
      ]
    )
  } else {
    return(
      x[
        do.call(CJ, sub),
        .SD,
        .SDcols = sel,
        on = names(sub),
        nomatch = nomatch
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the code used to generate the graph if anyone is curious:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot)
require(microbenchmark)
require(scales)

subsel <- function(x, sub, nomatch = NULL, sel = list()){
  if(length(sel) == 0) sel <- names(x)
  return(
    x[
      do.call(CJ, sub),
      .SD,
      .SDcols = sel,
      on = names(sub),
      nomatch = nomatch
    ]
  )
}

subsel2 <- function(x, sub, nomatch = NULL, sel = list()){
  if(length(sel) == 0) sel <- names(x)
  return(
    x[
      do.call(
        pmin,
        Map(`%in%`, x[, .SD, .SDcols = names(sub)], sub)
      ) == 1L,
      .SD,
      .SDcols = sel,
      nomatch = nomatch
    ]
  )
}

ll <- list(
  a = letters[1:10],
  b = 1:10,
  c = letters[1:10],
  d = 1:10
)

times <- rbindlist(
  lapply(
    seq(from = 100000, to = 1000000, by = 25000),
    function(y){
      dat <- data.table(
        a = sample(letters, y, replace = T),
        b = sample.int(100, y, replace = T),
        c = sample(letters, y, replace = T),
        d = sample.int(100, y, replace = T)
      )
      return(
        rbindlist(
          lapply(
            2:4,
            function(x){
              return(
                setDT(
                  microbenchmark(
                    subsel(dat, sub = head(ll, x), sel = letters[2:4]),
                    subsel2(dat, sub = head(ll, x), sel = letters[2:4])
                  )
                )[, fields := x]
              )
            }
          )
        )[, size := y]
      )
    }
  )
)

times[
  ,
  expr2 := unlist(
    lapply(
      as.character(expr),
      function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, '(', fixed = T))[1]
    )
  )
]
times[
  ,
  expr2 := factor(
    expr2,
    levels = c('subsel', 'subsel2'),
    labels = c('CJ', 'pmin + Map + %in%')
  )
]

ggplot(times, aes(size, time, group = expr2, color = expr2)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_grid(factor(fields) ~ .) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(scale = 1e-6)) +
  labs(
    title = 'Execution Time by Fields to Subset on',
    x = 'Dataset Size',
    y = 'Time (Milliseconds)',
    color = 'Function'
  )
```