# reactiveValuesToList Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would expect `reactiveValuesToList()` to return a plain ol' list, but it appears I have to trigger the reactive expressions stored in the resulting object before going about my business. Is there a reason for this? Am I misunderstanding the function?

In this particular case, I am wondering why the first method of getting `vals2` does not work and I have to use the workaround immediately following it. It throws the error message `Error in : 'match' requires vector arguments`.

```
#' Packages
#' ================================================================= #

load_pkgs <- function(pkgs){
  #' Loads a list of packages, installing them if not already
  #' installed pkgs is a vector of package names as strings
  #' =============================================================== #
  for(pkg in pkgs){
    if(!(require(pkg, character.only = TRUE))){
      install.packages(pkg)
      library(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }
}

load_pkgs(
  c('bit64', 'data.table', 'magrittr', 'shiny', 'shinydashboard',
    'shinyWidgets')
)

#' Data
#' ================================================================= #

dataset <- data.table(
  sample(letters, size = 1000, replace = T),
  sample(LETTERS, size = 1000, replace = T),
  sample.int(10, size = 1000, replace = T)
)

#' Functions
#' ================================================================= #

subsel <- function(x, sub, sel = NULL,
                   nomatch = getOption('datatable.nomatch')){
  #' function to subset a data.table (x) using a named list (sub). sel
  #' can be used to return only the specified columns. algorithms
  #' copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728200/subsetting-a-data-table-based-on-a-named-list
  #' and cutoff decided on some ad hoc testing.
  if(is.null(sel)) sel <- names(x)
  if(x[, .N] < 200000L){
    return(
      x[
        do.call(
          pmin,
          Map(`%in%`, x[, .SD, .SDcols = names(sub)], sub)
        ) == 1L,
        .SD,
        .SDcols = sel,
        nomatch = nomatch
        ]
    )
  } else {
    return(
      x[
        do.call(CJ, sub),
        .SD,
        .SDcols = sel,
        on = names(sub),
        nomatch = nomatch
        ]
    )
  }
}

excelStyleFilterUI <- function(field, dataset){
  #' server for filter on one variable
  #' args -
  #' - field - character string naming field in dataset
  #' - dataset - base dataset
  #' =============================================================== #
  nm <- paste0('filter_', field)
  ns <- NS(nm)
  vals <- dataset[, sort(unique(get(field)))]
  pickerInput(
    inputId = ns('filter'),
    choices = vals,
    selected = vals,
    options = pickerOptions(
      actionsBox = TRUE,
      selectedTextFormat = 'count',
      virtualScroll = TRUE,
      dropupAuto = F,
      liveSearch = TRUE,
      dropdownAlignRight = 'auto'
    ),
    multiple = T
  )
}

excelStyleFilterServer <- function(field, dataset){
  #' server for filter on one variable
  #' args -
  #' - field - character string naming field in dataset
  #' - dataset - reactive, filtered version of dataset
  #' =============================================================== #
  nm <- paste0('filter_', field)
  moduleServer(
    nm,
    function(input, output, session){
      # observer to update selection with allowable choices
      observeEvent(
        dataset(),
        {
          updatePickerInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = 'filter',
            selected = dataset()[, sort(unique(get(field)))]
          )
        }
      )
      
      return(reactive({ input$filter }))
    }
  )
}

#' App
#' ================================================================= #

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      actionButton('apply', label = 'Apply')
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = 'letters filter',
        excelStyleFilterUI('V1', dataset = dataset),
        width = 4
      ),
      box(
        title = 'LETTERS filter',
        excelStyleFilterUI('V2', dataset = dataset),
        width = 4
      ),
      box(
        title = 'numbers filter',
        excelStyleFilterUI('V3', dataset = dataset),
        width = 4
      )
    ),
    box(
      title = 'Dataset',
      tableOutput('tab')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  # reactive, filtered version of dataset
    # initial version of filter vectors
  vals <- reactiveValues()
    # reactive code
  filterset <- eventReactive(
    {
      input$apply
    },
    {
      # vals2 <- isolate(reactiveValuesToList(vals)) # Why doesn't this work below?
      
      vals2 <- lapply(
        names(vals),
        function(x) vals[[x]]()
      )
      names(vals2) <- names(vals)
      
      subsel(dataset, vals2)
    }
  )
  
  # pickers + filter values
  vals[['V1']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V1', filterset)
  vals[['V2']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V2', filterset)
  vals[['V3']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V3', filterset)
  
  # table output
  output$tab <- renderTable({
    filterset()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `vals` is a `reactiveValues` object, which contain `reactive` objects. `reactiveValuesToList` actually transforms your `reactiveValues` object into a list, which still contain `reactives`. That is you have to "call" them in order to get their value (like `vals[[1]]()`).

In fact you do not really need `vals` to be reactive itself unless you want to add some logic to react ive (pun intended) there is a new element added.

Replacing `vals <- reactiveValues()` by `vals <- list()` would equally work (and removes some small overhead).

Whatever you decide, at some point you have to loop through the *`reactive`* elements of `vals` and retrieve their values.

Thus, I would write your server like this:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
   vals <- list() # can also be changed to reactiveValues()...
   # reactive code
   filterset <- eventReactive(
      {
         input$apply
      },
      {
         vals2 <- lapply( 
            # ...however the implicit transformation to a list here 
            # is better done explicitly in this case 
            # reactiveValuesToList(vals)
            vals, 
            function(x) x()
         )
         
         subsel(dataset, vals2)
      }
   )
   
   # pickers + filter values
   vals[['V1']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V1', filterset)
   vals[['V2']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V2', filterset)
   vals[['V3']] <- excelStyleFilterServer('V3', filterset)
   
   # table output
   output$tab <- renderTable({
      filterset()
   })
}
```

---

### Bonus answer

You should put your `box` with the table in a `fluidRow` to avoid the content spilling the box:

```r
fluidRow(
   box(
         title = 'Dataset',
         tableOutput('tab')
      )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you have any insight into why the `reactiveValues` class exists? Your observation that I could simply use a list made me even more confused about that part of my question.

Comment: `reactiveVal` and  `reactiveValues` are basically wrappers for a single value and a list respectively. What is adds though, is reactivity. It is, whenever we change something the observers are notified and can run some code. These wrappers are mainly used to store reactive inputs and use them between observers. Last difference: reativeValues will notify its oberservers when you add an element, which a list of reactives does not